# Navigation - Fixed

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I'm trying to create a site with a slightly complicated navigation. I've gotten the navigation to look like I want to on initial load, but now am trying to get it to sticky nav to the top on scroll. I've been able to get a class to be created when the navigation bar hits the top, but cannot get it to sticky. Every time I add a position it jumps back down. Any advice or help would be great.

Here is the site: http://www.figadvertising.com/anne/

The div that needs fixed on scroll is moduletable_menu which also gets main-nav-scrolled added as a class when it gets to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the following styles will fix the navigation in question to the top of the menu when the class `main-nav-scrolled` is added.

**CSS**

```
.main-nav-scrolled .top-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.main-nav-scrolled .top-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you really need to so is add the actual styling to the `.moduletable_menu ul` element instead of the parent element. So just add the following styling to the child element (tested in DevTools):

```
.moduletable_menu.main-nav-scrolled ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Currently, it doesn't look like there's any styling associated with the new `class`. Try this out and let me know if it works on your end!